# Changing Burma to Myanmar?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

It seems we have had this discussion earlier, but taking into account that the United Nations refers to Burma as Myanmar, I don't understand why do we need to keep calling it burma. I don't have any issues with the tag, but a synonym would be nice.

Although I propose that we call in Myanmar because to me it seems akin to keep calling Russia as USSR or Germany as Prussia. I don't disagree that the logic is different, but it still seems that it would be appropriate to call them what they wish to be called rather than what we like to call them.

Comment: Have a read of [Wikipedia's thought on the matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Burma#Controversies)

Comment: [And note that we sort of went through this in the past](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/myanmar-or-burma?rq=1) although I think much of it happened in the chat.

Comment: @MarkMayo I did. But I still feel there's nothing wrong with a synonym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags renamed. [myanmar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myanmar) is now the master, [burma](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burma) is the synonym. The tag wiki has been edited to reflect the change.